# delay or stop execution for some time in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

hi i want to delay the execution of code for some time on buton click i cal a func named chance() .. 
which gets called after a picture box.image change .. bt the image does not change nd func chance() starts ... i want delay in chance() after the picture is changed ... thus help me ..

code

```
Private Sub p11_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles p11.Click
        row = 1
        col = 1
        chck()      'function which returns hit var value
        p11.Enabled = False     
        If hit = 1 Then
            p11.Image = Image.FromFile("G:\visual progs\BATTLESHIP\hit.png")
        ElseIf hit = 0 Then
            p11.Image = Image.FromFile("G:\visual progs\BATTLESHIP\miss.png")
            lblstatus.Text = "COMPUTER's TURN ... PLEASE WAIT ... "
            chance()    ' func begins 
        End If
    End Sub

 Function chance()
            ***'here i want a pause for 2 sec*** 
        Dim z As Int16 = 1
        While z = 1
            row = mnw.Next(9) + 1
            col = mnw.Next(9) + 1
            If c(row, col) = False Then
                c(row, col) = True          
                z = 0
            End If
        End While
        chck1()             ' checks for hit or miss for computer
        changepic()         'changes pic hit or miss for computer
        Return 0
    End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a pause of 2 seconds, you simply need to suspend the thread by doing this:

```
 Thread.Sleep(2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

Although you can use Thread.Sleep to introduce a delay, it has generally undesirable side-effects, in particular the form and its controls become unresponsive. A better way is to use a timer - that way the form is still responsive (e.g. you can move it around).

Also, you seem to be a little unsure of where to use a Sub and where to use a Function. A Sub does something, and a Function is used to return a value, ideally with *no* side-effects.

You could try this with a new Windows Forms project and just a PictureBox named `p11` and a Label named `lblStatus`:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Dim tim As Windows.Forms.Timer

    Const GAMEPATH As String = "G:\visual progs\BATTLESHIP\"
    Dim HitImgFile As String = Path.Combine(GAMEPATH, "hit.png")
    Dim MissImgFile As String = Path.Combine(GAMEPATH, "miss.png")

    Private Sub SetUpTimer()
        tim = New Timer
        tim.Interval = 2000 ' milliseconds
        tim.Enabled = False
        AddHandler tim.Tick, AddressOf Chance

    End Sub

    Private Sub Chance(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        tim.Enabled = False
        ' your code for the computer's turn goes here

        lblStatus.Text = "Your turn"
        p11.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Private Function IsHitByUser() As Boolean
        ' placeholder code for the actual check
        If Rnd() < 0.5 Then
            Return True
        End If

        Return False

    End Function

    Private Sub DoComputerTurn()
        lblStatus.Text = "COMPUTER's TURN ... PLEASE WAIT ... "
        p11.Enabled = False
        tim.Enabled = True

    End Sub

    Private Sub p11_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles p11.Click
        If IsHitByUser() Then
            p11.Image = Image.FromFile(HitImgFile)
            lblStatus.Text = "HIT"
        Else
            p11.Image = Image.FromFile(MissImgFile)
            DoComputerTurn()
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub StartGame()
        lblStatus.Text = "Your turn"

    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SetUpTimer()
        StartGame()

    End Sub


End Class
```